# Get data from serialized field in Magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to create a report of grouped items ordered in our Magento store, through mysql. Unfortunately, that data is stored in a serialized array in sales_flat_order_item.product_options, like this:

```
a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:1:{s:20:"super_product_config";a:2:{s:12:"product_type";s:7:"grouped";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"563";}}s:20:"super_product_config";a:3:{s:12:"product_code";s:12:"product_type";s:12:"product_type";s:7:"grouped";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"563";}}
```

What I need is the product_id in that array. Is there an easy way to do that through mysql?  I'll have to get that ID back out into the query so I can get the SKU from the product table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping to do the query directly in mysql. It'll be a bit more difficult to get all the data in php. Not impossible, just a bit more time.